# ¿Como seleccionar solo el ultimo array de un objeto de arrays que le paso a laravel lumen?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, lumen

pues eso pongo la imagen de postman me llega el objeto de array desde angular y quiero seleccionar solo el ultimo

este es mi codigo de lumen he probado con esto pero me da error puede ser por la libreria pero nose

```
 use Illuminate\Support\last;


 $data =$request->json()->All()->last();
 return response()->json([$data],200)
```

Postman

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

lo que me responde el backend laravel lumen

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Veo que tratas de obtener datos enviados desde una petición ajax, mi pregunta es ¿cómo envías dicha información? Ya que tengo entendido Laravel no tiene ninguna función llamada `json`.

Si pudieras agregar cómo estás enviando la información sería de gran ayuda.

Comment: laravel lumen si tiene esa funcion la estoy enviando en formato raw

Comment: Por si acaso, Laravel sí tiene un método json()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como es un arreglo, basta con usar la función `end()` que provee `PHP`.

```
$last = end($request->all());
```

Más información de la función `end()`en la documentación de `PHP`:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.end.php

Comment: error 'Only variables should be passed by reference'

Comment: Usando únicamente `$request->all()` tomando en cuenta que los únicos datos que recibes son esos, no debería haber ningún problema.

Comment: ahora si funciona

Comment: $final = end($data);